# How to get caption of ListBox control

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

How can I get the caption of ListBox control.

I have handle to Listbox control.

I tried with following , but it returned empty string

```
SendMessage(hListBox,WM_GETTEXT,MAX_PATH,(LPARAM)wszCaption);
```

Any suggestion of how to get the caption associated with ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

A listbox doesn't have a caption.

I presume you are trying to get the text of an (selected) item in the listbox itself?

```
::SendMessage(hListBox, LB_GETTEXT, nIndex, (LPARAM)lpszBuffer)
```

Will fetch the text for the `nIndex` item.  You can get the required minimum length for the buffer by asking the control

```
::SendMessage(hListBox, LB_GETTEXTLEN, nIndex, 0);
```

The return value is the required length.

see: [LB_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761313(VS.85).aspx), [LB_GETTEXTLEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761315(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, `WM_GETTEXT` should the caption of a listbox. Unfortunately, at least as far as I know, a list box won't normally display its window text. That means if it has a visible caption, it's probably something like a static control sitting next to the list box, and you'll need to figure out what static control it is, then read *its* window text to get what looks like the list box's caption.